# Question about functionally independence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m$ be polynomials in $n$ variables, $n>m.$
Suppose we know that any $m-1$ of the polynomials are functionally independent. Can we deduce now that all $m$ polynomials are functionally independent?

Polynomials $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_m$  in $n$ variables, $m \leq n$,  are called functionally independent if the rank of its [Jacobian  matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) equals exactly $m.$

Comment: No. Find some set of $m$ linear equations in $n$ variables that are linearly dependent, but any $m-1$ linear equation subset is independent. Find polynomials such that their partial derivatives are the coefficients of the corresponding linear equation.

Comment: @Don Thousand..thank you!